# How to debug "git send-email" failed issue?

Tags: git, email, smtp, sendmail

I want to use `git send-email` to send a patch.  The `.gitconfig` file is like this:

```
[user]
        name = Nan Xiao
        email = xxxxxx@chinadtrace.org
[sendemail]
        smtpencryption = ssl
        smtpserver = mail.chinadtrace.org
        smtpuser = xxxxxx@chinadtrace.org
        smtpserverport = 465
        smtppass = xxxxxxxxxx
```

The output of `git send-email` command is like this:

```
[root@localhost linux]# git send-email --smtp-debug --to xxxxxx@gmail.com 0001-xxxxxx.patch

......

Send this email? ([y]es|[n]o|[q]uit|[a]ll): y
Unable to initialize SMTP properly. Check config and use --smtp-debug. VALUES: server=mail.chinadtrace.org encryption=ssl hello=localhost.localdomain port=465 at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 1308.
```

The `tcpdump` capture packet likes this:

```
tcpdump: listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
01:45:15.201553 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29480, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    localhost.localdomain.38225 > cp-41.webhostbox.net.urd: Flags [S], cksum 0xecfd (incorrect -> 0x21a6), seq 2849543224, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 188147472 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
01:45:16.204505 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29481, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    localhost.localdomain.38225 > cp-41.webhostbox.net.urd: Flags [S], cksum 0xecfd (incorrect -> 0x1dba), seq 2849543224, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 188148476 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Although I have added "`--smtp-debug`" option, I still can't analyze the root cause. Could anyone give some clues?

**Update:**
I find the cause is my server uses a proxy, but how can I let `git send-email` to use this proxy?

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem? I am facing a similar one and I wonder how to solve it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Did a format patch before sending the email `git format-patch HEAD~..HEAD`
- ran this command in terminal `git send-email 0001-my-commit-name-generated.patch`
- What worked for me is the fact that we have a Self Signed certificate, and this is what I used in `~/.gitconfig` (global git config). Try giving it ssl cert path from your local machine, every Debian has one.

  ```
  [sendemail]
    from = Dani Carvahal <dani.carvahal@example.com>
    smtpserver = mail02.buc.example.org
    smtpuser = dani.carvahal@example.com
    smtpencryption = tls
    smtpsslcertpath = /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/example-cacert.pem
    smtppass = justmyemailpassword
    chainreplyto = false
    smtpserverport = 25
    to = Bob Smith <bob.smith@example.com>
    bcc = Dani Carvahal <dani.carvahal@example.com>
  ```